# i'm having a lighting bug problem

Tags: lighting

I was working on a model and this started happening to it I don't know how to fix it
Thanks 
Nano
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you could add another picture where the actual geometry is visible, that would make it much easier to see what is wrong. Also, have you tried recalculating the normals of your mesh?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you so much!